# How to prevent Eclipse from showing the opened file in package explorer

Tags: eclipse, navigation, package-explorer

somehow I've ended up in a situation such that when I navigate through source files with Eclipse, the Eclipse always selects (and expands) the opened file with package explorer. With this I end up

- losing my location on Package Explorer
- Having my Package explorer expanded and pretty confusing.

With brief googling/exploring on the preferences I couldn't find this one..

Eclipse version is 3.4 if that happens to matter.

Thanks in advance,
Touko

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Turn off the "Link with Editor" option in the Package Explorer toolbar.

[image: Package Explorer] (the left/right arrow icon, turned on here)

Comment: man, I was looking just for the opposite, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Select a source file, right click on it, choose "Open with" and then "Java Editor". The Java Editor should be the default after that for all java files.

Comment: It's 10 years old answer,  but can you please adjust your answer? :)