# How to automatically scroll to file location in Eclipse "open resource" (ctrl+shift+r)?

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse I use "CRTL + SHIFT + R " to "open resource" i.e. search and open a file.
How can I make eclipse automatically scroll over to the location of the file?

I work on a large project and it's annoying to have to click my way to the package folder of the file.

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334241/how-do-i-show-an-open-file-in-eclipse-package-explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable *"Link with Editor"* in your Project/Package Explorer. Then when you open the file, it will automatically scroll to its location within the package view.