# Point to an already open file in project pane on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, shortcut

How to point to an already open file in project pane?
Basically something like [How do I show an open file in eclipse Package Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334241/how-do-i-show-an-open-file-in-eclipse-package-explorer) but on Android Studio.

Comment: this has been asked & answered in the context of intellij: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086041/locate-current-file-in-intellij